# Bootstrap + Wordpress overlapping column issue

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I've started diving into WP code for theme customization, yet I suddenly saw a serious bootstrap column fla where I can't really locate the problem.

I've designed the blog section as `col-xs-12 col-sm-4` for the thumbnailed side image, and `col-xs-12 col-sm-8` for the content itself. Everything is fine and dandy in all size stretches except for 768px-990px where the columns start to overlap each other, in approx the same size as the margin they should have from each other.

Here is the code:

```
   <div class="row">
        <?php if( has_post_thumbnail()): ?>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
        <div class="thumbnail-img"><?php the_post_thumbnail('medium'); ?>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8">
            <p><?php the_content(); ?></p>
        </div>
        <?php else: ?>

        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <p><?php the_content(); ?></p>
        </div>

        <?php endif ?>
        </div>
```

Here are a few pictures to emphasize:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

> **EDIT:**

I changed, just to check, what happens if instead the 8-4 row, I will do a 6-6, and it works great (picture included below). isn't 8 + 4 = 12? what am I missing here?
[image]

Comment: Have you assigned img-responsive class to the thumbnail image?

Answer (score 0):

Try giving image width 100% so that it fits in div when resizing.

Or create a fiddle and share link.

Answer (score 0):

I've found out that wordpress doesn't really play nicely with bootstrap since `the_post_thumbnail('$string')` would overlap the bootstrap column grid if they aren't set right (WP doesn't auto set the image width into a column restricted area.)

`the_post_thumbnail('$string')` receives the following set params:

- `the_post_thumbnail( 'thumbnail' );`     // Thumbnail (150 x 150 hard cropped)
- `the_post_thumbnail( 'medium' );`        // Medium resolution (300 x
  300 max height 300px)
- `the_post_thumbnail( 'medium_large' );`  // Medium Large (added in WP
  4.4) resolution (768 x 0 infinite height)
- `the_post_thumbnail( 'large' );`         // Large resolution (1024 x
  1024 max height 1024px)
- `the_post_thumbnail( 'full' );`          // Full resolution (original
  size uploaded)

**There is no 100%** for `the_post_thumbnail('$string')` yet i'm just guessing that it could be hardcoded into the function itself as a param.

My solution was either using `$string = thumbnail` or changing the grid to `col-sm-6` for both columns.

Answer (score 0):

Place the url of the image in a img tag with the img-responsive class.